# Json add additional payload in the request

Tags: python, json

I am very new to Python. I run into this problem and hope you can help. Let me explain what I try to do and let me know if I am confusing you.

I have this Python script and it works fine with creating an event.

```
# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events?$Select=Start,End'
user = 'user1@domain.com'

pwd = getpass.getpass('Please enter your AD password: ')

# Create JSON payload
data = {
  "Subject": "Testing Outlock Event",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "Test Content"
  },
  "Start": "2016-05-23T15:00:00.000Z",
  "End": "2016-05-23T16:00:00.000Z",
      "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user1@domain.com",
        "Name": "User1"
      },
       "Type": "Required"  },

       {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user2@domain.com",
        "Name": "User2"
      },
       "Type": "Optional"  }
  ]
}

json_payload = json.dumps(data)

# Build the HTTP request
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json_payload)
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
# Perform the request
result = opener.open(request)
```

Since other posts suggest to set properties for Json separately ([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/223b2e54-4b3f-4f3d-822a-534c93b18b1f/outlook-calendar-office-365-rest-api-creating-meeting-with-attachment-in-it?forum=appsforoffice)) for the attachment, so I include the data_attachment code below in addition to the request (see "data_attachment" and "json_payloadAttachment"). However, I am not sure how to add that in the request and make one POST.

```
# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events?$Select=Start,End'
user = 'user1@domain.com'

pwd = getpass.getpass('Please enter your AD password: ')

# Create JSON payload
data = {
  "Subject": "Testing Outlock Event",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "Test Content"
  },
  "Start": "2016-05-23T15:00:00.000Z",
  "End": "2016-05-23T16:00:00.000Z",
      "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user1@domain.com",
        "Name": "User1"
      },
       "Type": "Required"  },

       {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user2@domain.com",
        "Name": "User2"
      },
       "Type": "Optional"  }
  ]
}

data_attachment = {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
            "Name": "test123.txt",
            "ContentBytes": "VGVzdDEyMw=="
    }

json_payload = json.dumps(data)
json_payloadAttachment = json.dumps(data_attachment)

# Build the HTTP request
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json_payload)  # NOT Sure where to put the attachment payload here
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
# Perform the request
result = opener.open(request)
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to merge the data; for example you can add another key to your data dictionary called `Attachments` which contains an array of dictionaries and merge them that way; then serialize your data to JSON.
You don't need `json_payloadAttachment`.

```
...
data["Attachments"] = [data_attachment]
json_payload = json.dumps(data)
```

You're also missing the `HasAttachments` key according to the link you posted.

```
data["HasAttachments"] = True
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried as you suggested, but no luck (no error either).  Maybe the suggestion from the link I posted was unclear.  If you have a moment, please read the response in that link where it said "I got it to work.... It would have been nice if the documentation actually listed this as one of the properties that had to be set." Please see if you can understand and provide suggestion.  I am really appreciated your help with this.